# suitability of math.stackexchange VS a study group for questions arising from independent study

Tags: discussion

I'm independently studying Jim Hefferon's [linear algebra book](http://joshua.smcvt.edu/linearalgebra/book.pdf) , and would like to know math.stackexchange is the best place to post questions that I have while studying the material. A study group would be better suited for these types of questions, but as it happens I don't know anyone else interested in the subject. I like how helpful everyone is on math.stackexchange, but I don't want my questions to be littered throughout the site; ideally I'd like them to be more centralized (again as they would be in a study group).

- Is math.stackexchange an appropriate place for these types of questions?
- Are there any other online resources geared toward independent study that I could use?

Comment: I don't have time to write an in-depth answer, but the answer is essentially "yes, but make sure you show some effort."  The one question you have asked does show effort, so I don't think you'll run into any problems there.  Once you get enough rep, you can also ask questions in the [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics)--people can respond quickly there.

Comment: @anorton: Thanks. The chatroom sounds like a good option. I'll try to build up my rep and follow the guideline you suggested.

Comment: Why the downvote? What is there to disagree with here?!